# Null Pointer Exception on a 2D array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, exception, null, pointers

I have a class, "Tetris", in which one of the instance variables is "board". "board" is 2D array of Color objects. Upon the creation of a tetris object I call a method that sets the dimensions of board and then sets all of the Color objects to be the Default value, that is to say, Color.blue.

```
public Tetris(int rows, int cols) {
  this.rows = rows;
  this.cols = cols;
  reset(rows, cols);
}

public void reset(int rows, int cols) {
  Color[][] board = new Color[rows][cols];
  for(int i  = 0; i<this.rows; i++) {
    for(int j  = 0; j<this.cols; j++) {
      board[i][j] = DEFAULT_COLOR; //  Color.blue; //DEFAULT-COLOR
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the code (which obviously has not been posted in its entirety) I get a null pointer exception on the line:

```
board[i][j] = DEFAULT_COLOR; //  Color.blue; //DEFAULT-COLOR.
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the NPE, but in reset you should either pass in rows/cols OR use this.rows/this.cols, but not both. Also, the Color[] is created locally, and not returned or set to an instance field.

Comment: Do you have a class member named board? If so your reset function, as Jon mentioned, does not initialize that member since your local variable board overrides the class member, which never get initialized.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you *would* post a short but complete program which demonstrated the problem. The code you've posted isn't enough to throw an exception, but I can see how with a few changes it might.

In particular, it seems odd to me that you're declaring a new local variable within your `reset` method... and you *also* have an instance variable called `board`? I suspect the solution may be as simple as changing the start of `reset` to:

```
board = new Color[rows][cols];
```

If your real code uses the local variable to create the array, but then tries to assign values via the instance variable, that could very well be the cause of the problem.

It also seems wrong that you're passing `rows` and `cols` into the method, and using those parameters in one place but the instance variables `this.rows` and `this.cols` in the loop. Why bother passing them at all?

Answer (score -2):

I think you must allocate every one of those colors like this:
    board[i][j] = new Color(...

Comment: There's no need for that - using DEFAULT_COLOR will just mean each array element refers to the same object. In particular, that wouldn't cause a NullPointerException in the assignment.